# How to adjust vertical spacing in MS Word when two different fonts are on the same line of text

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, fonts

I'm setting up the cover pages for a musical work and listing the instrumentation required.  The text I need to display is

> Flute 1-2
> Oboe 1-2
> Clarinet in B*b* 1-2
> Bassoon 1-2
>
> Horn in F 1-4
> Trumpet in B*b* 1-2
> Trombone 1-3
> Tuba

... and so on.  In the above, the italic *b* should be the musical flat symbol.

In MS Word (Home and Student 2019), I have typed the plan text in Century Gothic and used the Petrucci music font for the flat symbol.  The vertical spacing is off whenever the flat symbol appears, however.

I played around with the advanced font tools, but I could only raise or lower the symbol by a specified number of points. The vertical spacing anomaly remains regardless.

Does anyone know how to adjust the spacing for this symbol, or does anyone have a simple workaround?  Below is a screenshot of the text as I see it now.

[image]

Comment: You might simply try using an Italicized *b* superscripted.

Answer (score 1):

A few other possibilities:

Use a smaller point size for the flat character. (Changing the character scale in Font->Advanced will probably leave the character with the same vertical spacing so I don't think that would work).

If all you want is the same spacing for all the paragraphs and you don't really mind if it's larger than the default, put a flat character in each paragraph in the list and colour it white.

Select the paragraph containing the flat symbol, right-click and select the *Paragraph* option. In the Line spacing drop-down, select **Exactly**. Word should suggest a spacing in points which is probably the spacing Word is using for the default font for the paragraph's style. e.g. in my test here, it's 12pt. Accept it.

Alternatively set all the paragraphs in the list to have *Line* *spacing:* **Exactly** with the same point size. The **Exactly** setting will cut off characters that do not fit within the spacing so you will need to ensure you allow enough spacing for all your paragraphs, and you will need to modify the spacing if, for example you decide to use larger text for these paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone can find a *better* way to fix this, because this method uses absolute positioning for the flat symbol and it would be very easy for the spacing to get messed up, but this is a work-around that I used.

1. Create a text-box with the correct flat symbol.
2. Set it to have no outline, and to appear behind the text.
3. Drag it and nudge with arrows to position it where needed.